# Pulling data and printing it in an HTML table

Tags: php, mysql

From a MySQL table called "submission" containing the fields "loginid, submissionid, title, url, datesubmitted, displayurl", I would like to print an HTML table thats contains all "title" and corresponding "datesubmitted" where "loginid" equals "$profile."  The code I am trying to use is below.  It isn't working.  Any ideas why it isn't working?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
$profile = $_GET['profile'];  

$sqlStr = "SELECT loginid, submissionid, title, url, datesubmitted, displayurl
             FROM submission
            WHERE loginid = $profile
         ORDER BY datesubmitted DESC";    

$result = mysql_query($sqlStr);

$arr = array(); 
echo "<table class=\"samplesrec\">";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="sitename1"><a href="http://www.'.$row["url"].'">'.$row["title"].'</a></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="sitename2">'.$row["datesubmitted"].'</a></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Can't see anything wrong, other than a potential SQL injection. What are you getting, and what did you expect?

Answer (score 1):

Your query is probably failing.

Try echoing the return from mysql_error(); after trying the query to see what the issue might be.

You should also protect your input against injection.  If loginID is a username, you need to surround a string in a mySQL query with quotes - if loginID is a username.  If it's an integer you may be okay.

There are more robust ways to do this but simply:

```
  $profile = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['profile']);

  $sqlStr = "SELECT loginid, submissionid, title, url, datesubmitted, displayurl
               FROM submission
              WHERE loginid = '$profile'
           ORDER BY datesubmitted DESC";

  $result = mysql_query($sqlStr);

  if($result) {
      // Handle output
  } 
  else {
      echo 'query failed';
      // don't leave this here in production!
      echo mysql_error();
  }
```

Comment: "id" tends to indicate a number, which doesn't require quotes.

Comment: Case of answering too quickly, there :D saw it and had the edit going already!

Comment: Hi... I tried this, but nothing came up.  It didn't even say "query failed."  It's as if the query is not even there.

Comment: Can you edit your post above to include the connection information? Your database connection may have failed.  (change the password, hostname, username etc to something generic, obviously!).

You can also try a simple query you know will work like "SELECT NOW();" and try running that through mysql_query() to make sure.

Comment: The database is connecting.  I just tried some other code that requires a database connection and it worked fine.

Comment: I think I figured out what I am doing wrong... I will keep you posted.

Comment: This didn't work because "loginid" was not supposed to match $profile... I had to try a join query and someone else on Stackoverflow told me how to do it in another question.  Your suggestion sort of help me notice my error.

Answer (score 0):

One problem I can see is you are not checking in the return value of `mysql_query()`

`mysql_query()` returns `false` if it fails to execute the query. So you need to do a check, something like:

```
$result = mysql_query($sqlStr);
if(! $result) {

  //....error occured...prepare $message
  die($message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your question regards to **debugging**, the most important programming art. Noone can find an error for you, you have to do it yourself. With help of little tricks.

change `$profile = $_GET['profile'];` to `$profile = intval($_GET['profile'];)`

change `$result = mysql_query($sqlStr);` to

```
$result = mysql_query($sqlStr) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$sqlStr);
```

andd following 2 lines at the top of your code, run it again and see what it say. if still nothing, you don't have matching records in your table.

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```